# How to access application object in Silverlight class library?

Tags: silverlight

Suppose my solution have two project:

myApp: silverlight application project: the default application App

MyLib: silverlight class library project

then in code for those controls in Mylib, how to access the application object App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.Current should do you right, box as necessary((MyAppClass)Application.Current).something